# Androidx: WorkManager's enqueue method is not running the Worker

Tags: android, kotlin, worker, androidx, android-workmanager

I want to run a custom `Worker` - `NotificationWorker` - that shows an notification on the device, and I set the date & time to display it using a `WorkRequest`.

This is my method to enqueue a `WorkRequest`, that gets called in a UI class (in my app it's a Fragment):

```
fun notifyUserAt(dt: LocalDateTime, title: String, text: String) {
    val epoch = DateUtil.toEpochMilli(dt)
    val now = DateUtil.toEpochMilli(
        ZonedDateTime.now(AppRepository.zoneId).toLocalDateTime()
    )
    val delay = epoch - now + 10

    val data: Data = Data.Builder()
        .putString(NOTIF_TITLE, title)
        .putString(NOTIF_CONTENT_TEXT, text)
        .putLong(NOTIF_DATETIME, epoch)
        .build()

    val constraints: Constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.NOT_REQUIRED)
        .setRequiresCharging(false)
        .build()

    val notificationWork = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationWorker>()
        .setInputData(data)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .setInitialDelay(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(notificationWork)
}
```

Note that the **delay** variable is set to **10** milliseconds (very close to no delay) when testing this out.

This is my Worker class:

```
class NotificationWorker(val context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) :
    Worker(context, params) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {

        // Get data
        val title = inputData.getString(NOTIF_TITLE)
        val contentText = inputData.getString(NOTIF_CONTENT_TEXT)
        val epoch = inputData.getLong(NOTIF_DATETIME, 0L)

        // Build the notification
        val mNotification =
            NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NORMAL_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentIntent(overviewScreenIntent(context, epoch))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build()!!

        val id = newNotificationId
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
            .notify(id, mNotification)

        return Result.success()
    }
```

I set a breakpoint when debugging in the last line of the `doWork` method in my `NotificationWorker`, but the program doesn't pause there. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, this is solved by setting a small icon to the notification via `setSmallIcon(icon)`. After that notifications are showing up perfectly.